# Fedora 19 Installation issue

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I have downloaded the fedora 19 DVD iso and want to use it to install through USB.

I have used the Linux live creator & other tools to make it bootable. The installer runs correctly but it fails to get the source for installation and says:

```
Error setting up source for installation.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Guide/Making_USB_Media.html) for installing to a USB stick - but try refering to the ones relating to the use on `dd` [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Guide/Making_USB_Media-UNIX_Linux.html).

---

**Note:** Fedora 20 has been released TODAY *(17/12/2013)*- http://fedoraproject.org/en_GB/get-fedora - so you might want to use that instead.

Comment: Note: Fedora 20 is now released.

Comment: Finally... I'll edit my answer @Risto..

Comment: tried everything but still not satisfied